# Online GAE Application User

Tags: google-app-engine

How to know if a user is currently logged-in in your Google App Engine application?

The application allow its users to browse other users' profile. If the viewed profile is also using or logged-in in the application, i want a notification that the viewed profile is online.

How to achieve this requirements?

Answer (score 1):

If you are managing user profiles, you know when a user logs in. At the end of the login process, just save the user's log-in information in the memcache somehow.
You will later be able to check if a user is logged-in just by searching for him in your memcache.

This way is easy to catch and track the connection events, but you also have to react when a user disconnects, to have your list up to date. To achieve this, you can use a Channel. See the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections).

Answer (score 1):

You could, as Gaël suggests, use the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) to track this, but it's probably overkill. If you wanted to go that route, just listen for the connected & disconnected messages, and update a field in the db that indicates that the user is signed in.

A less expensive route might be to just update a field in your user's record that's something like "last time this user requested a page." If it's been more than *n* minutes since the last time the user requested a page, assume they're signed out. Indeed, you could even do this in memcache with a map from userid to last access time.

It comes down to what you want to do with the "signed in" information: if you just want to give a general sense of whether a user's around, or how many users are online, using the datastore or memcache solution is probably good. On the other hand, if you want to reflect the user's presence so they can respond to eg. IMs, then you'll probably want the Channel API anyway so you can immediately deliver messages to them.